# How to Successfully Deploy a Lightswitch 2013 HTML App to Azure with a Linked SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, azure, visual-studio-lightswitch

I've created a Lightswitch HTML application in VS 2013. It relies on a SQL Server database which was created locally and then uploaded to Azure. The database was then linked to the Azure web site.

I tested my database connection strings in the publish routine and they succeeded. The publish succeeded, but when I browse my azure URL, I receive the following message:

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

What must be done to remedy this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem that would not resolve until I moved to a "Pay-As-You-Go" subscription rather than a "Free Trial".

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem, but did NOT have to move to a "Pay-As-You-Go" subscription to get it working.  Here was what I had to do.

The Azure management portal will tell you that the Site URL is something like 
 https://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/
but to test a Lightswitch HTML5 client application, the URL in Azure will *actually* be 
https://mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/HTMLClient/

Hope that helps.